# which layout should i use

Tags: android, gridview

i am extremely new to android development so excuse what may seem to be a dumb question, but im really stuck...
i am trying to make an activity that has a large number of scrollable rows. each row contains text and images as shown in the image. there are three columns and the second column spans two rows the widths of the columns is also different (the centre one is bigger than the other two which are equal). each row is basically a button to take user to a new activity. 
how do i create this kind of layout. ive tried using nested linear views with each row being a horizontally oriented linear view containing two vertically oriented linear views but that seemed a bit comlicated. what about gridview etc? (not that i even understand how gridviews work anyway)

would really appreciate an answer
maybe whoever answers could eave out the button-to-new-activity for now just so i understand the layout problem for now

Comment: Hi Dennis, welcome to Stack Overflow! The best questions have a some _relevant code_ of what you have tried and a brief explanation of _why_ it doesn't work, as explained in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). In this case a picture, even a crude drawing, would help explain what you are trying to do in less words.

Answer (score 0):

please check this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

avoid unnecessary nesting of layout you can use relative layout instead of nested linear layout

you can take look at this also

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/